# How to configure correctly to receive the prediction result in Seldon Core python client?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubeflow, seldon

I'm checking out with Seldon Core on Minikube and have successfully deployed a model on a cluster. 
I tested with below code:

```
seldon-core-api-tester ../seldon-core/examples/models/keras_mnist/contract.json     `minikube ip` `kubectl get svc -l app=seldon-apiserver-container-app -o jsonpath='{.items[0].spec.ports[0].nodePort}'`     --oauth-key oauth-key --oauth-secret oauth-secret -p
```

and got the right prediction result looking like this.

```
RECEIVED RESPONSE:
meta {
  puid: "gn83vb2ag419k547eqkhfduos2"
  requestPath {
    key: "mnist"
    value: "mnist:0.1"
  }
}
data {
  names: "t:0"
  names: "t:1"
  names: "t:2"
  names: "t:3"
  names: "t:4"
  names: "t:5"
  names: "t:6"
  names: "t:7"
  names: "t:8"
  names: "t:9"
  ndarray {
    values {
      list_value {
        values {
          number_value: 0.00026227490161545575
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.0007252057548612356
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.028986405581235886
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.8030332922935486
        }
        values {
          number_value: 7.914198795333505e-05
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.14541368186473846
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.002676495350897312
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.015001941472291946
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.0034872409887611866
        }
        values {
          number_value: 0.00033424459979869425
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I was trying to use the python client,

```
from seldon_core.seldon_client import SeldonClient
sc = SeldonClient(deployment_name="mnist",namespace="seldon", seldon_rest_endpoint= '127.0.0.1:30790')
r = sc.predict(transport="rest")
```

I got this error.

```
HTTPConnection object at 0xb2bb5a780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Could someone help me find out what's wrong?

```
$kubectl get svc
mnist-deployment-mnist   ClusterIP      10.99.10.81      <none>        8000/TCP,5001/TCP               2d22h
kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                         4d22h
seldon-core-redis-master             ClusterIP      10.107.217.176   <none>        6379/TCP                        2d22h
seldon-core-seldon-apiserver         NodePort       10.106.34.6      <none>        8080:30790/TCP,5000:31866/TCP   2d22h
seldon-mnist-0-1-4249605       ClusterIP      10.101.205.227   <none>        9000/TCP                        2d22h
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `seldon-core-api-tester` script, you provide `minikube ip` as an argument (along with the ambassador port). You'll need this address for the endpoint when you initialize the client instead of `127.0.0.1`. So first run in your shell

```
minikube ip
```

and take a note of the ip, then find the ambassador port

```
kubectl get svc ambassador -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}'
```

then your client and call will look sth like this

```
from seldon_core.seldon_client import SeldonClient
import numpy as np

# this is the ip from `minikube ip` and port from `kubectl get svc ambassador -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}'`
minikube_ambassador_endpoint = "192.168.99.108:32667"

deployment_name = "mnist"
namespace = "default"

sc = SeldonClient(
    gateway="ambassador",
    gateway_endpoint=minikube_ambassador_endpoint,
    transport="rest",
    deployment_name=deployment_name,
    namespace=namespace
)

response = sc.predict(
    data=np.ones((5,)), 
    deployment_name=deployment_name, 
    payload_type="ndarray"
)
print(response)
```